# How come the onBackPressed() in a toolbar doesn't react?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toolbar, onbackpressed

I am trying to implement the onBackPressed() in my toolbar to go back to the MainActivity.

I used it in another project and it worked without fail.
In this project the back arrow doesn't react.

The MainActivity is the parent of the other activity (Manifest).

EDIT: With the override onBackPressed function the back arrow reacts after multiple taps..

Many thanks

```
  if (happyPlaceDetailModel != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbarHappyPlaceDetail)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.title = happyPlaceDetailModel.title

        binding.toolbarHappyPlaceDetail.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            onBackPressed()
        }
```

Layout file:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.HappyPlaceDetailActivity">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_happy_place_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/CustomToolbarStyle"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Manifest :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/happy_place_background"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.HappyPlaces">
    <activity android:name=".activities.HappyPlaceDetailActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/CustomNoActionBarTheme"
        android:label="Happy Place details"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.AddHappyPlaceActivity"
        android:label="Add a Happy Place"
        android:theme="@style/CustomNoActionBarTheme" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

Comment: Could you share your layout file? Are you inside an Activity or a Fragment?

Comment: Inside an Activity (the back arrow works within another activity, but not this one) 



    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_happy_place_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/CustomToolbarStyle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

Comment: Please edit your question and add it similarly to how you've added your kotlin code. On the comments is pretty hard to read since they don't alow formatting

Comment: Sorry pal! Haven't realised it was so messy in the comment. Thanks for you help

Comment: @AnnaB can you please post you manifest here if there's nothing confidential. Also if you have override `onBackPressed()` method, can you also post that implementation?
You can do one thing from your side. You can put some logs around the suspected code which you're expecting to be executed and check if those logs are printing or not.

Comment: what happens if you replace `onBackPressed()` with `finish()` in your Click Listener?

Comment: @CSmith same thing- no reaction

Comment: then I suggest this Click listener code isn't running at all...check in a debugger or via log statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the belated answer.

When you set your toolbar like this:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setSupportActionBar(tb_chat_profile)
        supportActionBar?.apply {
            setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
            setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        }
}
```

You need to handle the click event on the Activity menu hook:

```kotlin
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean =
        when(item.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> {super.onBackPressed(); true }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
```

This approach is a sort-of legacy approach, which don't get me wrong it works and it's still right!

But the modern thing apps do nowdays is manually adding the a Button inside the Toolbar in the layout xml file like so:

```xml
<!-- This is pseudo-code, pasting it is likely to not work and it's just for demo purposes -->
<!-- You can play with the location of the button with the toolbar's 'gravity' property --> 
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
     android:id="@+id/toolbar">
     <ImageButton android:id="@+id/back"/>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

And finally set a listener like how you would do it in any other case:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    binding.back.setOnClickListener { 
        /*assuming you're inside an activity*/
        finish() 
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using this?

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        onBackPressed()
        return true
}
```

I don't suggest you use "!!", it would be better to use ".?" because it can give you a NullPointerException.